# Clunky animation with Dismissible and Provider (NotifyListener)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-provider

I am trying to fix an issue that occurred when using the **Dismissible** widget and the **Provider package**.

When I dismissed a card this is called :

```
 Provider.of<NMyProvider>(context, listen: false).toggleIsDone(object.id);
```

The provider :

```
Future<void> deleteNotebook(int id) async {
    ...
    final notebookId = _items.indexWhere((notebook) => notebook.id == id);
    ...
    _items.removeAt(notebookId);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This makes the animation clunky with noticeable lag but does not occur when removing the NotifyListeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the entire screen is being rebuilt upon notification from the provider. There are some solutions for that:

1. Move the `Consumer<NMyProvider>`/`context.watch<NMyProvider>(context)`/`Provider.of<NMyProvider>(context, listen: true)` closer to its usage. Flutter only rebuilds the widgets that use the same `context`;
2. Use a unique `key` for every notebook. Not the index position, but a unique key like the `notebookId`. Flutter will re-use the already built notebook widget where the key is the same in between builds;
3. Split the `NMyProvider`: Move everything that doesn't make sense to this provider into other providers. If a lot of unrelated states are together the chance of this provider being used by the root widget gets higher. `NMyProvider` should deal only with the list of notebooks state;

Comment: Thank you, I had to refactor my code and it is now much smoother.